# How would I write a sendAction helper?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

In ember, we have the action helper;

```
{{action "actionName" arg1 arg2}}
```

But, when I want to send actions to a parent component, I still have to explicitly write an action on the child that calls sendAction. Even if I'm ONLY bubbling an action. I'd like the avoid this with a send-action helper;

```
{{send-action "actionKey" arg1 arg2}}
```

Does anyone know how I'd implement this helper?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use closure actions instead, as shown in [Triggering Changes with Actions](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.15.0/components/triggering-changes-with-actions/).

So if you have an action in a parent component named `actionKey`, you do the following.

Pass it to the child component as a closure action:

```
{{my-component myName=(action 'actionKey')}}
```

And then in the template of your child component:

```
<button {{action myName arg1 arg2}}>click me</button>
```

I used `myName` for illustrative purposes, it can be whatever you want as long as it matches the name you use inside the component.

I have reproduced the above in a Twiddle: https://ember-twiddle.com/fd56b0b9d017968fc334b3f109760806.

Comment: I'm trying to imitate your pattern exactly, but I keep getting an error;  
`<frontend@component:my-component::ember4889> had no action handler for: 'actionKey'`

Comment: wait, my mistake was someplace else, I think this is the right answer. The fix is to use `myName` instead of `"myName"`  
So, follow-up question if you don't mind, how would I instantiate a closure action in a controller (rather than the template), so I can pass references to it around. Is this possible?

Comment: Ask way! Pass it around to whom? The template syntax I showed above is the way to pass closure actions to components.